# How to transfer files recovered using photorec on gparted usb

Tags: data-recovery, gparted

I had some files which were important to me on a laptop on which I was running Lubunutu. I then installed Xubuntu "over the top" of my Lunbuntu installation, choosing the option to erase the disk while doing so... essentially wiping the laptop's SSD HDD.

Well, I would like to recover the files that were overwritten.

After some searching and researching, I found out about tstdisk and photorec... I read that, in order to not further complicate the task of recovering the files I should not use the HDD on which the data was stored. I therefore choose to use gparted on USB thumb drive which would allow me use tstdisk & photorec.

I know this is all basic enough so far... and it seems to me that photorec is indeed recovering the files that I want...

Although, the final step of how to transfer the files from the usb installation of gparted to a more permanent media is eluding me...

I create a directory on the gparted usb into which I store the files "recovered-files"... though, when I shut down the laptop and then try plugging my usb gparted install (where I expected to find the recovered files) into another machine... I cannot find the "recovered-files" directory.

Can anyone advise me on the final step of transferring the recovered files while I am using gparted on a live usb?

I'd appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: How did you create the USB boot drive with gparted? Did you clone from the iso file or did you create a FAT32 partition and extract from the iso file to the FAT32 partition? The method to make it possible to save files will depend on that.

Comment: I formatted the USB thumbdrive to FAT32 using windows... I then downloaded the gparted iso, and created a bootable version of gparted on the thumbdrive using the gparted iso with Universal-USB-Installer-2.0.1.4a

Comment: I *think* that on live (live-only) drives, the FAT32 partition is read-only. Maybe not in Windows, but definitely in Linux with `gparted` (booted from another drive), you should be able to shrink the FAT32 partition and create unallocated drive space 'behind' it. Then create a new partition with a suitable file system (ext4 if only Linux, exFAT if also Windows and MacOS) and use that partition to store your recovered files. - But the easy solution is to dedicate another drive for storage (if you have another drive).

Comment: If you have no other separate drive, you can create a persistent live system with Lubuntu or Xubuntu, for example using [**Rufus**](https://rufus.ie) in Windows or [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) in Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I ended up getting somewhere with... what I did was to reformat the usb thumb drive... then partitioned it using Windows Disk Management... two separate partitions using FAT32. I used one for re-creating the live gparted iso... and then was able to copy the restored files over to the other partition on the thumb drive. Although, photorec was didn't restore any the files I was initially after... so a bitter sweet result... thanks for help all the same though

Comment: Thanks for sharing your results. You share this bitter sweet result with many other users. Let this experience help you set up a backup routine, so that you always keep your important files backed up. Good luck with your Linux systems :-)